# Will access through segment register incur more overhead?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

Assuming an instruction accesses memory and stores a register's content into it, on x86_64 architecture. For Example,

> mov rax, [rip + offset1]

My question is, if the segmentation is enabled, and the access to same memory address was done with segment register, will it incur more overhead(latency or throughput)?For Example,

> mov rax, gs:[rip + offset2]

Comment: You are unlikely to be using `gs` together with `rip`. That said, I don't think it incurs any penalty.

Comment: Every memory operand access is done through a segment register. The difference between the two instructions you've given as examples is that first uses DS and the second uses GS and is one byte longer in order to encode the segment override prefix.

Comment: @RossRidge Not in long mode where segmentation is effectively disabled except for `fs` and `gs` which don't work in the normal way either.

Comment: @Jester You're right, but I stiil want to know the situation when  `rip` was replaced with a general register like `rcx`

Comment: @fuz It's still the same in long mode, the first instruction uses DS as the segment register. In long mode the DS base and limits are ignored (unless AMD's LSMLE extension is enabled), but every memory operand has an implicit or explicit segment register.

Comment: Maybe if you are really tight on some cache, then that additional prefix byte in opcode may flip it over.... I don't think it's possible to hit this one in real world, it would be maybe impossible to even demonstrate on purpose. But if the final address lands into some memory outside of cache, ordinary cache miss penalty does apply. That's why I have this feel "prefixed `mov` is slower" in my head, because most often when the different segment was used, it was also "cold" memory outside of cache.